# View parameter values while debugging with method call of many parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Let's say I'm degugging code and I reach a breakpoint where the line of code is something like this:

```
GetEmpInfo(empName, empLast, empSS, empDept, empBirth, empCity, empState, 
empCountry, parm1, moreparms, evenmore, toomanyparms);
```

Is there a way to know what value each of those parameters has without going through each variable? I know there has to be a way; I just don't know where it is.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first of all you should not have those many parameters for a single method!

Comment: You know, I knew someone was going to post something like that. Stick to the question please!

Comment: If OP is using visual-studio-2010 they're likely fixing someone else's old code. Give them the benefit of the doubt, I say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 7 good ways to do it -

```
1. Data Tip
2. Autos Window
3. Locals Window
4. Watch Window
5. Quick Watch Window
6. Parallel Watch Window
7. Immediate Window
```

[Check this for more info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Which one do you suggest for this particular issue? Because I've seen most of these and I don't think they'll give me all the parameters in the method call.

Comment: I personally use Autos Window or add watches most of the times. If its just one time required, you might just use hovering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DebuggerDisplay Attribute

```
 [DebuggerDisplay("{Param1} {Param1} {Param1}")]
```

And when you hover over the object you will see the values that are entered above

Comment: I get "There is no default constructor for this type" deep in webforms pipeline. I have no information about the type though. I don't have source type to debug. How do I get to know which was the type the pipeline was trying to instantiate?